# Trying to disable Keycloak and Spring Security with WebMvc test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have a springboot application using spring security and keycloak. when executing the application, securing with jwt tokens works as expected.

then i have a seperate test application.yml where i try to disable keycloak, as found in tutorials in the web.

for webmvc tests, this does not work as expected. although i try to disable everything security and keycloak related, still `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` tries to use the `KeycloakConfigResolver` class, not finding it.
it then falls back to load the keycloak.json file and fails.

what do i have to make MockMvc tests work? i just want to have every request permitted as implemented in the configure HttpSecurity method. keycloak basically shouldnt be used for mockmvc tests.

**pom:**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
[...]
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>19.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Config:**

```
keycloak:
  enabled: false
  realm: mock 
  resource: mock 
  auth-server-url: http://mock 
  bearer-only: true
  credentials:
    secret: mock
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakAutoConfiguration
```

**Keycloak Bean Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = ["keycloak.enabled"], havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = false)
class KeycloakDisabledConfig: KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(){

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .permitAll()
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**")
    }

    override fun sessionAuthenticationStrategy(): SessionAuthenticationStrategy = RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(
        SessionRegistryImpl()
    )
```

**Test:**

```
@WebMvcTest(value = [OrganizationController::class], excludeAutoConfiguration = [SecurityAutoConfiguration::class])
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@Import(value = [
    OrganizationMapper::class
])
internal class OrganizationControllerTest{

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mockmvc: MockMvc
```

**loaded context:**

```
Positive matches:
-----------------

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#basicErrorController matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration#errorAttributes matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (server.error.whitelabel.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - ErrorTemplate Missing did not find error template view (ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.ErrorTemplateMissingCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#beanNameViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration#defaultErrorView matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: error; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   GsonAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   GsonAutoConfiguration#gson matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.google.gson.Gson; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   GsonAutoConfiguration#gsonBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   GsonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.google.gson.Gson' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (server.servlet.encoding.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration#characterEncodingFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter' (OnClassCondition)
      - NoneNestedConditions 0 matched 1 did not; NestedCondition on HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition.ReactiveWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.NotReactiveWebApplicationCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration#messageConverters matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConverters; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.StringHttpMessageConverterConfiguration#stringHttpMessageConverter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperBuilderConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapperBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration#jacksonObjectMapper matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration.ParameterNamesModuleConfiguration#parameterNamesModule matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.module.paramnames.ParameterNamesModule; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.converters.preferred-json-mapper=jackson) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'jacksonObjectMapper' (OnBeanCondition)

   JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration#mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ignored: org.springframework.hateoas.server.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter,org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.alps.AlpsJsonHttpMessageConverter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   KeycloakDisabledConfig matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (keycloak.enabled=false) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   MockMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   MockMvcAutoConfiguration#dispatcherServlet matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   MockMvcAutoConfiguration#dispatcherServletPath matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.DispatcherServletPath; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   MockMvcAutoConfiguration#mockMvc matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   MockMvcAutoConfiguration#mockMvcBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration NONE cache type (CacheCondition)

   SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer', 'org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration#securityFilterChainRegistration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (names: springSecurityFilterChain; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'springSecurityFilterChain' (OnBeanCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration#pageableCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration#sortCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.data.web.config.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' (OnClassCondition)

   TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration#applicationTaskExecutor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: java.util.concurrent.Executor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration#taskExecutorBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.task.TaskExecutorBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'objectPostProcessor'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider,org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService,org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManagerResolver,org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder,org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.introspection.OpaqueTokenIntrospector,org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository,org.springframework.security.saml2.provider.service.registration.RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator' (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnResource found location classpath:META-INF/services/javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider (OnResourceCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration#defaultValidator matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: javax.validation.Validator; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration#methodValidationPostProcessor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#formContentFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.formcontent.filter.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#flashMapManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: flashMapManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#localeResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: localeResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#themeResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: themeResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#requestContextFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener,org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found beans 'defaultViewResolver', 'beanNameViewResolver', 'mvcViewResolver'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: viewResolver types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to locate Keycloak configuration file: keycloak.json
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.loadKeycloakDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.java:83) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-19.0.1.jar:19.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AdapterDeploymentContextFactoryBean.java:76) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-19.0.1.jar:19.0.1]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.adapterDeploymentContext(KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:72) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-19.0.1.jar:19.0.1]
    at com.jschausberger.demo.keycloak.KeycloakDisabledConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef3c2204.CGLIB$adapterDeploymentContext$13(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.jschausberger.demo.keycloak.KeycloakDisabledConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef3c2204$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3c55188.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at com.jschausberger.demo.keycloak.KeycloakDisabledConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ef3c2204.adapterDeploymentContext(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not use Keycloak adapter for Spring (`keycloak-spring-boot-starter`). [It is very deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187) and not compatible with spring-boot 3 (RC1 this week, release in November). Use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` instead. Article [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-oauth2-resource-servers), more tutorials [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials).

Second, do not disable security in your unit-test. Use mocked authentication and use it to unit-test your security rules. You might refer to article and tutorials linked above to figure out how.